# Azure kubernetes - Application with Session management?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, session-state

I am planning to deploy the Asp.net application that uses session on Azure kubernetes. How do I make sure that the incoming request goes to the same pod where session is created.

Comment: You need to plan that ahead of time...if you are running just one replica then there is no problem, but if you are working with several replicas, then you should separate the session layer from your application...this can be easily accomplished using something like redis for your session layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that apps deployed on Kubernetes has a design following the [The Twelve Factor App](https://12factor.net/).

Everything will be easier if the app is *stateless* and *share nothing* with other instances. See [Twelve Factor App - Processes](https://12factor.net/processes)

> Twelve-factor processes are stateless and share-nothing. Any data that needs to persist must be stored in a stateful backing service, typically a database.

> Some web systems rely on “sticky sessions” – that is, caching user session data in memory of the app’s process and expecting future requests from the same visitor to be routed to the same process. Sticky sessions are a violation of twelve-factor and should never be used or relied upon. Session state data is a good candidate for a datastore that offers time-expiration, such as Memcached or Redis.

Using [Redis](https://redis.io/) is one way to store temporary data belonging to the user.

For authentication, I would recommend to use OpenID Connect with JWT tokens in the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header. See e.g. [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/b2c/) for an example of an OpenID Connect provider.